# Pinging IP Address Using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ip-address, ping

How to create **syntax query sql** to Pinging IP Address, like command prompt.

```
ping 192.168.xx.xx
```

i use SQL Server 2008 Standard.

Comment: Why do you need to? This is usually something that would be done in the application layer, not the data storage layer.

Comment: Have a look at [`xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [CLR integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/clr-integration-overview?view=sql-server-2017). Though I really wonder why you want to ping using SQL Server.

Comment: Diado, i handle both of them.
Sticky Bit, Thanks.. its work..


EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'ping 192.168.1.1'